# Probability in a group of people

Tags: probability, proof-verification, conditional-probability

What are the possibilities of $2$ people being in the same group (group of $5$ people) among $30$ people?

I thought of using conditional probability: given that a group has been chosen the probability that a person falls into it is $1/36$. I am wrong?

Comment: So, you have 30 people, and you split them into six groups of five people each and you are asking what the probability is that two specific people, say Mr. A and Mr. B happen to be in the same group?  Let us imagine for a moment that Mr. A is very impatient and forces his way into the front of the line and he gets assigned a group.  Now, the remaining four slots in his group can be filled by any of the remaining people.  We ask what the chance is that one of those four slots are taken by Mr. B.  $\frac{4}{29}$

Comment: It *looks* like your attempt was that you said "Mr. A has a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance to be in the first group" and similarly for Mr. B, and so you multiplied these together.  This ignores the fact that 1) We didn't care *which* group it was that A and B were in beyond the fact that they were in it together and 2) These are not independent events.

Comment: Doing it the normal way goes from 2/77

Comment: Where the hell did 2/77 come from.  I can't explain why what you did was wrong if I don't know what you did.

Comment: he number of possibilities of 2 specific people in the same group of 5 is found by putting them in the group, then choosing 3 others from remaining 28. ($\binom{28}{3}$). The total sample space is any 5 people from 30. ($\binom{30}{5}$). The number of possibilities divided by sample space gives the correct probability.

Comment: That is the probability that Mr. A and Mr. B are both in the first group.  You again neglected to consider the possibility that Mr. A and Mr. B are both in the second group, or are both in the third group etc...  $\binom{28}{3}/\binom{30}{5} = \frac{2}{87}$ not $\frac{2}{77}$.  Multiplying your result by six corrects the calculation, $\frac{2}{87}\times 6 = \frac{4}{29}$

Comment: If I have 2 people already determined, I just have to make the number of combinations of the 28 remaining 3 to 3, because no matter what the order

Comment: Thank you!!! Very good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To organize the comments above:

We may approach directly via definitions and counting principles.  There are $\binom{30}{5,5,5,5,5,5}$ different ways in which we assign the people to groups.  Of these, there are $6\cdot \binom{28}{3}\cdot \binom{25}{5,5,5,5,5}$ ways in which we assign people to groups such that Mr. A and Mr. B are both in the same group.  (*Six ways to choose the group, $\binom{28}{3}$ ways to choose who else is in their group, and $\binom{25}{5,5,5,5,5}$ ways to choose how to distribute the remaining people*).  Taking the ratio then, the probability is: $\frac{6\cdot \binom{28}{3}\binom{25}{5,5,5,5,5}}{\binom{30}{5,5,5,5,5,5}}$

Alternatively, we can break apart by disjoint events.  The probability that Mr. A and Mr. B are in the same group is equal to the sum of the probabilities of Mr. A and Mr. B both being in the first group plus the probability that Mr. A and Mr. B are both in the second group, etc... noting that it is impossible for them to both be in more than one group at a time.  We get for this an answer of $6\times \frac{\binom{28}{3}}{\binom{30}{5}}$ as found in the comments above (*Noting again the nuance of the question that we don't care /which/ group it was that they were in, just that they were together, something that the OP originally forgot*).

My preferred solution:

Let Mr. A force his way to the front of the line and get assigned a group first.  Now, lay out the available remaining places in a line.  Mr. B is equally likely to have been placed in any of the remaining $29$ places, only $4$ of which would be in the same group as Mr. A.  The probability is then $\frac{4}{29}$.  Very minimal calculation and arithmetic needed here.

All of the above approaches result in the same answer once simplified.